# Addition of time differences with where clause in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp

I have a data table with hundreds of thousands of rows which represent requests to servers to get data. Each record has a timestamp, the server ID and a binary value (tinyint) of whether the server responded correctly. The query times are not constant.

I am trying to get a total amount of time that the server was deemed to be 'online' by adding up the times between the queries where the server was online (very highly preferable a mysql query).
Eg.

```
server | time | status
1 | 1/1/2012 11:00 online
1 | 1/1/2012 11:02 online
1 | 1/1/2012 11:05 offline
2 | 1/1/2012 11:10 online
1 | 1/1/2012 11:30 online
Time now: 11:40
Server 1 Online Time = 2+3+10 = 15 minutes
```

Is it possible to do this in mysql? I would much prefer it over getting all the rows to php and calculating it or averaging anything.

Comment: what is the type of column ????????????/

Comment: not sure hows that considered to be "online" what are you going to use the metric for? SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Uptime'; makes more sense to me

Comment: @shail the server Id is an int, the timestamp is a timestamp and the online status is a tinyint (0,1)

Comment: @Dagon the rows represent queries sent to hundreds of remote servers at random intervals to eventually give a percentage of online time. But I don't just want the percentage, I want the raw time too

Comment: well i hope its not a botnet!

Comment: @Dagon haha, had a good laugh at that. I can assure you if you help me it is only for good and not evil

Comment: This could be done with a MySQL stored procedure analogous to rationalboss's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done using UNIX timestamp conversion and variable assignment on a properly sorted row set. By "properly sorted" I mean the rows must be sorted by `server`, then by `time`. Here's how you could use variables to get the online time (interval) in seconds since the previous event for every row in your table (called `server_status` for the purpose of this answer):

```sql
SELECT
  *,
  @currenttime := UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time`),
  @lasttime := CASE
    WHEN server <> @lastserver OR @laststatus = 'offline'
    THEN @currenttime
    ELSE @lasttime
  END,
  @currenttime - @lasttime AS seconds_online,
  @lasttime := @currenttime,
  @lastserver := server,
  @laststatus := status
FROM
  server_satus s,
  (SELECT @lastserver := 0) x
ORDER BY
  s.server,
  s.`time`
```

As you can see, a temporary variable (`@currenttime`) is initialised with the UNIX timestamp equivalent of `time`, another one is used to hold the previous timestamp so that the difference between the two could be calculated. Other variables are used to remember the previous server ID and the previous status, so that, when necessary, the difference was returned as 0 (which is done for every row which records a server's first event as well as those that come after `offline` events).

You could now just group the result set produced by the above query, SUM() the `seconds_online` values and divide them by 60 to get minutes (if you aren't happy with seconds), like this:

```sql
SELECT
  server,
  SUM(seconds_online) DIV 60 AS minutes
FROM (
  the query above
) s
```

Note, however, that the first query doesn't really calculate the servers' seconds spent online since their respective *last* events. That is, the current time might very well differ from that in any of the latest event records, and it wouldn't be taken into account, because the query calculates the seconds *per row since the previous row*.

One way to solve this would be to add one row per server containing the current timestamp and the same status as in the last record. So, instead of just `server_status` you would have the following as the source table:

```sql
SELECT
  server,
  `time`,
  status
FROM server_status

UNION ALL

SELECT
  s.server,
  NOW() AS `time`,
  s.status
FROM server_status s
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      server,
      MAX(`time`) AS last_time
    FROM server_status
    GROUP BY
      server
  ) t
    ON s.server = t.server AND s.`time` = t.last_time
```

The left part of the UNION ALL just returns all rows from `server_status`. The right part first gets the last `time` per server, then joins the result set to `server_status` to get hold of the corresponding statuses, substituting `time` with `NOW()` along the way.

Now that the table is completed with the "fake" event rows reflecting the current time, you can apply the method used in the first query. Here's what the final query looks like:

```sql
SELECT
  server,
  SUM(seconds_online) DIV 60 AS minutes_online
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    @currenttime := UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time`),
    @lasttime := CASE
      WHEN server <> @lastserver OR @laststatus = 'offline'
      THEN @currenttime
      ELSE @lasttime
    END,
    @currenttime - @lasttime AS seconds_online,
    @lasttime := @currenttime,
    @lastserver := server,
    @laststatus := status
  FROM
    (
      SELECT
        server,
        `time`,
        status
      FROM server_status

      UNION ALL

      SELECT
        s.server,
        NOW() AS `time`,
        s.status
      FROM server_status s
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT
            server,
            MAX(`time`) AS last_time
          FROM server_status
          GROUP BY
            server
        ) t
          ON s.server = t.server AND s.`time` = t.last_time
    ) s,
    (SELECT @lastserver := 0) x
  ORDER BY
    s.server,
    s.`time`
) s
GROUP BY
  server
;
```

And you can try it (as well as play with it) [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3082/11) too.

Comment: Wow thank you. This would have to be the longest and most detailed answer I've ever read on this site, pure quality.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sample table structure I created:

```
-- SQL EXAMPLE
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stack_test` (
  `server` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rtime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `stack_test` (`server`, `rtime`, `status`) VALUES
    (1, '2012-01-01 11:00:24', 1),
    (1, '2012-01-01 11:02:24', 1),
    (1, '2012-01-01 11:05:24', 0),
    (2, '2012-01-01 11:10:24', 1),
    (1, '2012-01-01 11:30:24', 1);
-- SQL EXAMPLE END
```

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT(`server`) `server` FROM stack_test';
$res = sql::exec($query); // replace with your function/method to execute SQL
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $server = $row['server'];
    $uptimes = sql::exec('SELECT * FROM stack_test WHERE server=? ORDER BY rtime DESC',$server);
    $online = 0;
    $prev = time();
    $prev = strtotime('2012-01-01 11:40:00'); // just to show that it works given the example
    while ($uptime = mysql_fetch_assoc($uptimes)) {
        if ($uptime['status'] == 1) {
            echo date('g:ia',$prev) . ' to ' . date('g:ia',strtotime($uptime['rtime'])) . ' = '.(($prev-strtotime($uptime['rtime']))/60).' mins<br />';
            $online += $prev-strtotime($uptime['rtime']);
        }
        $prev = strtotime($uptime['rtime']);
    }
    echo 'Server '.$server.' is up for '.($online/60).' mins.<br />';
}
?>
```

This is the output I get:

```
11:40am to 11:30am = 10 mins
11:05am to 11:02am = 3 mins
11:02am to 11:00am = 2 mins
Server 1 is up for 15 mins.

11:40am to 11:10am = 30 mins
Server 2 is up for 30 mins.
```

Comment: That is an absolutely fantastic answer however I am trying to get as much SQL and as little PHP as possible. Problem being that there are hundreds of thousands of rows and transferring every row to php is proving too slow